# Do Spark/Parquet partitions maintain ordering?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

If I partition a data set, will it be in the correct order when I read it back? For example, consider the following pyspark code:

```
# read a csv
df = sql_context.read.csv(input_filename)

# add a hash column
hash_udf = udf(lambda customer_id: hash(customer_id) % 4, IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('hash', hash_udf(df['customer_id']))

# write out to parquet
df.write.parquet(output_path, partitionBy=['hash'])

# read back the file
df2 = sql_context.read.parquet(output_path)
```

I am partitioning on a customer_id bucket. When I read back the whole data set, are the partitions guaranteed to be merged back together in the original insertion order?

Right now, I'm not so sure, so I'm adding a sequence column:

```
df = df.withColumn('seq', monotonically_increasing_id())
```

However, I don't know if this is redundant.

Comment: Incidentally, check out bucketBy: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#bucketing-sorting-and-partitioning That might do what you're trying to do with that UDF, but more efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed. Try it with even a tiny data set:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d')],['customer_id', 'name'])

# add a hash column
hash_udf = udf(lambda customer_id: hash(customer_id) % 4, IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('hash', hash_udf(df['customer_id']))

# write out to parquet
df.write.parquet("test", partitionBy=['hash'], mode="overwrite")

# read back the file
df2 = spark.read.parquet("test")
```

```
df.show()

+-----------+----+----+
|customer_id|name|hash|
+-----------+----+----+
|          1|   a|   1|
|          2|   b|   2|
|          3|   c|   3|
|          4|   d|   0|
+-----------+----+----+
```

```
df2.show()

+-----------+----+----+
|customer_id|name|hash|
+-----------+----+----+
|          2|   b|   2|
|          1|   a|   1|
|          4|   d|   0|
|          3|   c|   3|
+-----------+----+----+
```